# PayPal transaction with a mix of one time and recurring payments using Smart Payment Buttons

Tags: paypal

My project runs on products with both the one time and recurring payments. 
Right now I'm trying to integrate the paypal smart buttons, which would create one transaction consisting of one time and recurring payments. 
For example: The user adds to the cart Product1 (5$ one time payment) and Product2 (15$ recurring payment), which makes it a 20$ transaction. 
Is it possible to charge the user 20$ in the beginning and set a trial on the recurring product (Product2 in our case), which would charge the user from the next billing period?

Here's what I tried: 
On the js side I have the following code

```
createPayPalButton = function() {

    // setting up the details for the transaction
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '20.00'
                    }
                }]
            })
        },

     // setting up the details for subscription
     createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'MY_PLAN_ID'
            });
     },
}

$(function() {
    createPayPalButton();
})
```

But after running it I receive the following error: 
`Uncaught Error: Do not pass both createSubscription and createOrder`

I tried to find a solution on the paypal side, but I didn't manage to.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new bespoke plan with a `setup_fee` that corresponds to the amount of the one-time order.

Otherwise you need a separate checkout and transaction.